# How can express this imperative function in a functional, array-based language like K (or Q)?

Tags: functional-programming, k, kdb

How can express this imperative function in a functional, array-based language like [K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28programming_language%29) (or [Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28programming_language_from_Kx_Systems%29))?

In sloppy C++:

```
vector<int> x(10), y(10); // Assume these are initialized with some values.

// BTW, 4 is just a const -- it's part of the algorithm and is arbitrarily chosen.

vector<int> result1(x.size() - 4 + 1); // A place to hold a resulting array.
vector<int> result2(x.size() - 4 + 1); // A place to hold another resulting array.

// Here's the code I want to express functionally.
for (int i = 0; i <= x.size() - 4; i++) {
    int best = x[i + 0] - y[i + 0];
    int bad = best;
    int worst = best;
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        int tmp = x[i + j] - y[i + 0];
        bad = min(bad, tmp);
        if(tmp > best) {
            best = tmp;
            worst = bad;
        }
    }
    result1[i] = best
    result2[i] = worst
}
```

I would most like to see this in [kdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28programming_language%29#K_financial_products) and Q but other functional languages are welcome.

Comment: What is this code trying to do?

Comment: It is trying to calculate two things: First, at each point in x, we want the maximum over the next 4 elements (let's call this Nx = max(x), at location Px, where Px = 0..3. Second, at each point in x, we want the minimum over the next Px points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Kona](http://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) (an open-source K dialect):

First, set some example values (using same as the Clojure solution):

```
a:1+!8;b:8#0        / a is 1..8, b is eight 0s
```

Then:

```
{(|/x;&/x)}@+{4#y _ x}[a+b;]'!#a
```

Where **a** and **b** are your x and y variables above. (K makes a special case for the variables x, y, and z.)

To break that up a bit more:

```
maxmin:{(|/x;&/x)}  / (max;min) pairs of x
get4:{4#y _ x}      / next 4 from x, starting at y
                    / with <4 remaining, will repeat; doesn't matter for min or max
/ maxmin applied to flipped results of get4(a-b) at each index 0..(length a)-1
maxmin@+get4[a-b;]'!#a

/ result
(4 5 6 7 8 8 8 8
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Answer (score 5):

porting @silentbicycle's k directly to q yields

```
q)a:1+til 8
q)b:8#0
q){(max x;min x)}flip{4#y _ x}[a+b;]each til count a
4 5 6 7 8 8 8 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

another approach, slightly more vectorized (imao):

```
q){(max;min)@\:flip 4#'(til count x)_\:x+y}[a;b]
4 5 6 7 8 8 8 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) (a dialect of [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29)):

```
(defn minmax [x y](map #(vector (- (apply max %1) %2) (- (apply min %1) %2)))(partition-all 4 1 x) y)

(minmax [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])
```

will give

[([4 1] [5 2] [6 3] [7 4] [8 5] [8 6] [8 7] [8 8])`(result 1, result 2) as output..

Then

```
(map #(first %1) result) is result1
(map #(last %1) result) is result2
```